# Old sql script started throwing CTE "Types don't match" errors when compiler updated, wondering why

Tags: sql-server, odbc, installshield

Okay, yet another question that didn't get any good answers over on forums.asp.net so I thought I'd try here.

Our InstallShield code had a dll plugin to read and apply schema/data upgrade scripts via ODBC as part of the install process.  I had to do some work on our installer, so I moved the project to another machine and started work but a weird thing happened - a script that had been running without complaint suddenly started throwing

"Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column 'PathFromRoot' of recursive query "TempCategoryValue"

errors on a CTE when it didn't before.  And the only thing that had changed was the compiler version of our InstallShield plugin.

The script's old; it had been running without complaint for a couple of years.  The script was working on an old tree table representation, attempting to add and populate a string representation of the tree inheritance at every node.  The idea being you wouldn't need a lot of outer joins or recursive CTEs to tell where you were in the tree at any given time, since the new PathFromRoot column would tell you.

But updating the compiler from VS 2003 to VS 2010 suddenly changed how it saw the CTE expression.

Our C++ app skims through a text file and runs everything between GO statements as separate commands, though on the same connection.

I stared at the query for a while and couldn't see why it didn't think the types didn't match.  `[PathFromRoot]` was declared as `varchar(900) not null` in TreeTable and the CTE had an explicit `CONVERT(varchar(900),...)` on the recursive clause.

Anyone have any idea why it would suddenly see them as different?

```
-- Table as it existed to start, before the script ran
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TreeTable](
[TreeValueID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
[ParentValueID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- Add the PathFromRoot column to get a string representation of the tree hierarchy
ALTER TABLE TreeTable ADD PathFromRoot varchar(900) NOT NULL DEFAULT '.'
GO

-- Seed the new string column for the root tree values
UPDATE TreeTable SET PathFromRoot = CONVERT(nvarchar(25), TreeValueID) + '.'
WHERE ParentValueID IS NULL
GO

-- recursively update the rest of the PathFromRoot values
WITH TempTreeValue (ParentID, PathFromRoot, TreeValueID ) AS (  
-- anchor member definition  
SELECT ParentValueID, PathFromRoot, TreeValueID  FROM TreeTable  WHERE ParentValueID IS NULL
UNION ALL
 -- recursive member definition  
SELECT tv.ParentValueID,  CONVERT(varchar(900), tv.PathFromRoot + CONVERT(varchar(25), tv.TreeValueID) + '.') as [PathFromRoot], tv.TreeValueID 
   FROM TreeTable tv  
   INNER JOIN TempTreeValue ttv ON tv.ParentValueID = ttv.TreeValueID 
)
UPDATE TreeTable  SET PathFromRoot = ttv.PathFromRoot FROM TreeTable t JOIN TempTreeValue ttv ON t.TreeValueID  = ttv.TreeValueID 

...
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of the TreeTable and the exact error you get? Or better: Can you post the definition of the table and enough example data to reproduce the error?

Comment: Thank you for responding, Sebastian, and sorry for the delay on my side; work was keeping me distracted.  I've tried to flesh out the example better above.